# Laravel 5.8 : unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 3 bytes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, serialization

I have serialized data in DB:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"2";i:1;s:1:"5";}
```

when unserializing it in the blade, I get below error :

```php
@php($course_ids = unserialize($payment->course_id))
```

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 3 bytes
```

I use an attribute , but get the error :

```php
public function getCourseIDAttribute($value)
    {
        return isset($value) ? unserialize($value) : $value;
    }
```

or `casts` :

```php
protected $casts = [
         'course_id' => 'array',
    ];
```

and use this in blade :

```php
@php($course_ids = $payment->course_id)
```

I still have an error.

Notice: when using `dd` i can get array !! but without `dd` I get an error in blade !!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to serialise it twice. Once in the models' magic attribute and once in the view itself?

Comment: when using `attr` in the model, I useing `$payment->course_id` in blade

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: You said I unserialize 2 times. When I used the `attribute`, I did not unserialize in the blade again

Answer (score 0):

Here you are unserializeing the data,

```
public function getCourseIDAttribute($value)
{
    return isset($value) ? unserialize($value) : $value;
}
```

so you can drictly use it like a property in blade file there is no use of writing

```
@php($course_ids = unserialize($payment->course_id))
```

in blade file you can just write like this

```
@php($course_ids = $payment->course_id)
```

Hope it helps